# Switch between two objects' values - Django

Tags: python, django

I have this model:

```
class Person(models.Model)
    id = IntegerField()
    place_in_line = IntegerField()
```

I want to **avoid race conditions** in this code, I *Can't afford* to have two Person objects with the same place in like:

```
@transaction.atomic
def switch(person1, person2)
    place1 = person1.place_in_line
    place2 = person2.place_in_line
    person1.place_in_line = place2
    person2.place_in_line = place1
    person1.save()
    person2.save()
```

I have tried using F or Case expressions, but they all refer to themselves and not to other arbitrary field...

thanks.

Comment: Add a [unique](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#unique) parameter to the field?

Comment: well this is my current solution. it's not good enough since it would not perform the action... (I use retry with unique and transaction.atomic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is curious, I ended up wrapping this thing with `@retry` and it seems to operate pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

you can try,

```
with transaction.atomic():
    Person.objects.filter(id__in=person1).update(place_in_line=place2)
    Person.objects.filter(id__in=person2).update(place_in_line=place1)
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this will still not ensure that another instance will not switch priority with one of them and will get the same number...Ill edit the question to clarify that